# Why can't I read clickable links for webscraping with rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to webscrape this [website](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/news/speeches).

The content I need is available after clicking on each title. I can get the content I want if I do this for example (I am using SelectorGadget):

```
library("rvest")

url_boe ="https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/june/andrew-bailey-reuters-events-global-responsible-business-2021"

sample_text = html_text(html_nodes(read_html(url_boe), "#output .page-section"))
```

However, I would need to get each text for each clickable link in the website. So I usually do:

```
url_boe = "https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/news/speeches"


html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(url_boe), "#SearchResults .exclude-navigation"), name = "href")
```

I get an empty object though. I tried different variants of the code but with the same result.

How can I read those links and then apply the code in the first part to all the links?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that — idiotically — there are actually no links to speeches on the website. The links are inserted into the page *dynamically* using JavaScript. ‘rvest’ fundamentally can’t deal with this, you need to use something like ‘rselenium’ instead.

Comment: thanks a lot Konrad! I'll try with ''rselenium'. Thanks again for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KonradRudolph has noted before, the links are inserted dynamically into the webpage. Therefore, I have produced a code using `RSelenium` and `rvest` to tackle this issue:

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

# URL
url = "https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/news/speeches"

# Base URL
base_url = "https://www.bankofengland.co.uk"

# Instantiate a Selenium server
rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="91.0.4472.19")

# Assign the client to an object
rem_dr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to the URL
rem_dr$navigate(url)

# Get page HTML
page <- read_html(rem_dr$getPageSource()[[1]])

# Extract links and concatenate them with the base_url
links <- page %>%
  html_nodes(".release-speech") %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0(base_url, .)

# Get links names
links_names <- page %>%
  html_nodes('#SearchResults .exclude-navigation') %>%
  html_text()

# Keep only even results to deduplicate
links_names <- links_names[c(FALSE, TRUE)]

# Create a data.frame with the results
df <- data.frame(links_names, links)

# Close the client and the server
rem_dr$close()
rD$server$stop()
```

The resulting data.frame looks like this:

```
> head(df)
                                                                                         links_names
1                           Stablecoins: What’s old is new again - speech by Christina Segal-Knowles
2                       Tackling climate for real: progress and next steps - speech by Andrew Bailey
3                     Tackling climate for real: the role of central banks - speech by Andrew Bailey
4 What are government bond yields telling us about the economic outlook? - speech by Gertjan Vlieghe
5                              Responsible openness in the Insurance Sector - speech by Anna Sweeney
6                           Cyber Risk: 2015 to 2027 and the Penrose steps - speech by Lyndon Nelson
                                                                                                                       links
1 https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/june/christina-segal-knowles-speech-at-the-westminster-eforum-poicy-conference
2           https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/june/andrew-bailey-bis-bank-of-france-imf-ngfs-green-swan-conference
3             https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/june/andrew-bailey-reuters-events-global-responsible-business-2021
4   https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/may/gertjan-vlieghe-speech-hosted-by-the-department-of-economics-and-the-ipr
5         https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/may/anna-sweeney-association-of-british-insurers-prudential-regulation
6     https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/speech/2021/may/lyndon-nelson-the-8th-operational-resilience-and-cyber-security-summit
```